# SQL Server database support

Tags: sql-server, atk4

does Agile Toolkit support MS SQL Server database connection?

Under "atk4\lib\DB\dsql" folder i don't see a suitable driver.

I tried to do a test with sqlsrv driver, setting a proper dsn in config file.

But i have this application error when browsing a page:

```
File not found
Exception_PathFinder, code: 0
Additional information:
file: DB\dsql\sqlsrv.php
type: php
attempted_locations:
0: C:/wamp/www/lib/DB/dsql/sqlsrv.php
1: C:\wamp\www\atk4/lib/DB/dsql/sqlsrv.php
2: C:/wamp/www/atk4-addons/mvc/DB/dsql/sqlsrv.php
3: C:/wamp/www/atk4-addons/misc/lib/DB/dsql/sqlsrv.php
class: DB_dsql_sqlsrv
namespace:
orig_class: DB_dsql_sqlsrv
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It does not appear to out of the box: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/install/db

Comment: you should be able to use any PHP PDO supported database with little change. Please create an empty class DB_dsql_sqlsrv extends DB_dsql